# Как при помощи JQuery перетащить мышкой div с контентом в другой div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как один div перетащить мышкой в другой?
Я хочу какой-нибудь из блоков справа перетащить в левый и, если в левом блоке уже ранее вставлен другой, то заменить его.

Можно ли такое реализовать на JQuery?

```css
.content { border:1px solid #CCC; width:200px; height:100px; padding:5px; margin:10px 0px;}
.box { width:200px; height:50px; margin:10px 0px; border:1px solid #CCC;}
```

```html
<div style="float:left;">
  <div class="content">сюда перетаскивать контент</div>
  <div class="content">или сюда перетаскивать контент</div>
  <div class="content">или сюда перетаскивать контент</div>
</div>

<div style="float:right;">
  <div class="box">Перетащить box1</div>
  <div class="box">Перетащить box1</div>
  <div class="box">Перетащить box1</div>
  <div class="box">Перетащить box1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Sortable -> Connect lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Да можно. Нужно использовать draggable и droppable.

```
$(function(){
        $(".box").draggable();
        $(".content").droppable({
        accept: '.box',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(".box",this).remove();
                    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                    $(ui.draggable).removeAttr( 'style' );
                }
            }); 
    });
```

Вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/a9psqm6v/